# How to write C code which is similar to String.isNullOrEmpty in C#

Tags: c#, c

I've been C# developer.

But Now I have to write C code.

I used to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` for preventing Errors and assign a new string.

I hope to write C code to act like String.IsNullOrEmpty. and assign a new string

so I wrote some sample code.

```
static char *pCtvUrl;

void set_app_url(const char* appUrl){
     if(!appUrl || !*appUrl)
         return;
     pCtvUrl = malloc(sizeof(appUrl));
     strcpy(pCtvUrl,appUrl);
}
```

I want to check if this is correct or not.

If you know better way to solve, please give me some advice.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check for a NULL or empty string is correct

Change:

```
pCtvUrl = malloc(sizeof(appUrl)); /* This would allocate sizeof(char*) only. */
```

to:

```
pCtvUrl = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(appUrl) + 1)); /* '+1' is for null terminator.*/
```

You also need to `free()` memory of `pCtvUrl` before reassigning it:

```
static char *pCtvUrl = 0;
```

Before `pCtvUrl = malloc(...);` call `free(pCtvUrl);`.

Instead of using a global variable consider changing `set_app_url()` to return a copy of the string:

```
char* set_app_url(const char* appUrl)
{
    char* retVal = 0;

    if (appUrl && *appUrl)
    {
        retVal = malloc(strlen(appUrl) + 1);
        strcpy(retVal,appUrl);
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

The caller would be responsible for freeing the returned string.

Comment: thank you,  how about `malloc((sizeof(char)+1)*strlen(appUrl))` instead of  `malloc(strlen(appUrl) + 1)` ??

Comment: @sunglin sizeof(char) = 1 so `(1+1) * X != 1 * X + 1` for `X > 1`

Comment: @sunglim, `malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(appUrl) + 1));`.

Answer (score 1):

Checking whether `appUrl` is `NULL` or "empty" is correct.

However, calling your `set_app_url` function more than once will lead to memory leaks. You don't free previous `pCtvUrl`.

Also, you may have buffor underrun. You need to malloc `strlen(appUrl) + 1`. Anyway, I suggest `strdup` to use here, instead.

Comment: `sizeof(appUrl)` returns a size of a pointer, **not** the string length